# GSheets - remove everything *after* a word (but keep the word)

Tags: regex, google-sheets

How can I remove everything after a specific word (while keeping the word)?
I want to remove everything **after** the word 'films'.

```
"George Fellini 194 films 273 169  Edit" would turn into "George Fellini 194 films"
"Rick Bathista 7 films 10 27  Edit" would turn into "Rick Bathista 7 films"
```

There are many posts that are similar but aren't google sheets specific, and the two google sheets specific answers I've found eliminate the word I want to keep.

(It would be a bonus if it could also keep the singular "film" but not necessary.

What I've tried:

`=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"(.*) films .*")` - deletes the word 'films'

`=regexreplace(B2,"films ","")` - also deletes the word 'films'

my sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UL0cvdgbwJIAPSJTxajxM7_pw_pPqxq-Ofmt8uK6J6o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Use `=REGEXREPLACE(B2,"\b(films).*$","$1")` or `=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"^.*\bfilms")`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,".*films?")
```

[The documentation of REGEXEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) says:

> Extracts matching substrings according to a regular expression.

The regular expression matches any sequence of zero or more characters (`.*`) followed by `film` and an optional `s` (`s?`).

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B, "(.+films)")))
```

[image]

```
() - extract group of something
.+ - all characters / anything

(.+films) - extract group of all characters ended by films included
```